# How to pass XML widget id to ViewModel?

Tags: android-databinding, mpandroidchart, android-viewmodel

The target is when a button clicked, a chart refresh data.

I used MPAndroidChart, data binding layout.

The question is how can I get 'lineChart' from XML widget id?

And I think maybe it is not the right way to achieve this, what is the better way to refresh a chart when a button clicked?

Code in `xxxViewModel.class`:

```
fun onButtonClicked() {
    // how can I get 'lineChart' from XML widget id?
    plotChart(lineChart)
}

fun plotChart(lineChart: LineChart){
    //detail code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**We should not pass the view reference to the view model, this will break the MVVM architecture pattern**.

so view will call the viewmodel and perform some action VM and return the data via Live data.

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" 
/>
```

in the above code there is a xml attribute `android:onClick`. Map the name of the function, which is defined (action for click of button) in the activity/fragment.

```kotlin
fun onButtonClicked() {
    viewModel.plotChart(lineChart)
}
```

in the above method, view will call `viewModel` to `plotChart` method to perform action.

Comment: But there is 2 problem: 1, if I need to change say 20 properties, I have to create 20 LiveData to observe them; 2, say textSize and textColor always change at the same time, I would like to set them together, rather than set them separately.

Comment: instead of creating the many livedata, you can create single livedata, and put the different value in the data class. 
eg. data class Properties(var value1: string, var value2: string, var value3: string, .......)
and define LiveData as val currentName: MutableLiveData<Properties>. set the value in the ViewModel, observe it in the view,and change value of textview.